# How to autogenerate parameters in an input step from Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I would like to dynamically generate my parameters on an input step from a loop inside my Jenkins pipeline.

This is my code:

```
var = input message: 'Tags a saisir', ok: 'Build!',
        parameters: [
                     choice(name: 'name1', choices: file1),
                     choice(name: 'name2', choices: file2),
                     choice(name: 'name3', choices: file3),
                     choice(name: 'name4', choices: file4)
]
```

I would like to know if it is possible to generate each parameter from a loop like :

```
for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
   theChoice = "choice(name : "+myList.get(i)+'choices: file"+i+")
}
```

and generate the input step from those lines.

Is that kind of approach possible ?

The main goal is to generate an input step with modular variables dependending on the jenkins file clone from the Git SCM

Regards,

Guillaume

Comment: In your example `choice(name: 'name1', choices: file1)`,  `file1` is a variable which contains possible choices for `name1`?

Comment: @VitaliiVitrenko : yes, my objectif is that, the file1,file2 etc would be replaced by map.get(myList.get(i))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
def parameterNames = fileMap.keySet().toList()
def choices = []
for (int i = 0; i < parameterNames.size(); i++) {
   choices += choice(name : parameterNames[i], choices: fileMap[parameterNames[i]])
}

def var = input message: 'Tags a saisir', ok: 'Build!', parameters: choices
```

Where `fileMap` is a `Map` which contains possible choices fore each parameter name (key is a parameter name, value is a `String` of possible choices)

Comment: This is what i wanted : theorized it, but asked the question instead of trying by myself
thank you, hope this will help other people

Guillaume